# dojo framework - event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

I have a trouble in my code,
I want to send an ajax request by clicking a button,
but the request is automatically run, even when I don't click the button,
here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function set(mode) {

    var nomor_awal = dojo.query("input[name=nomor_awal]");
    var nomor_akhir = dojo.query("input[name=nomor_akhir]");

    var validGetUrl = "";

    validGetUrl += "nomor_awal="+objNomorAwal.attr("value")+"&";
    validGetUrl += "nomor_akhir="+objNomorAkhir.attr("value");

    dojo.xhrPost({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>register_perkara/pidana_biasa/"+mode+"/",
        content:{
            filter:validGetUrl
        },
        load:function(response){
            (response!="1")? document.location = window.location: null;
        }
    });
 }

 dojo.ready(function(){
    dojo.connect(dojo.query("input[name=filter]"), "onclick", set("set_filter"));
 }

</script>



<table>
 <tr>
  <td><label for="nomor_awal">Nomor awal</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="nomor_awal" size="8" value="" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><label for="nomor_akhir">Nomor akhir</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="nomor_akhir" size="8" value="" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="filter" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I don't click the filter button but the function are automatically executed, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know dojo, but this line

```
dojo.connect(dojo.query("input[name=filter]"), "onclick", set("set_filter"));
```

executes the `set` function and passes the return value to `dojo.connect`.

You have to pass the function, not call it. So I'm quite sure you want:

```
dojo.connect(dojo.query("input[name=filter]"), "onclick", function() {
    set("set_filter");
});
```

Comment: later I tried your code but i changed the code a little.
and alhamdulillah it's working :D

thanks a lot :D

code :

    `dojo.connect(dojo.query("input[name=filter]")[0], "onclick", function(evt){
        set("set_filter");
    });`

Comment: @Val: As I said, I don't know dojo, but this was the reason for why the function was executed immediately. I'm glad you figured it out :) Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you (by clicking the tick outline next to it).

Comment: `dojo.query("input[name=filter]").onclick = function (e) { set("set_filter"); };` should work as well!